# Change imports on aliases in all project

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have added aliases for import statements in my Angular project.
Now, I'd want to apply these aliases on all imports automatically, without changing imports manually.

WebStorm allows me to change it almost automatically one-by-one (see screenshot), but is there any way to do the same thing on all imports at once?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use **Fix all 'Import can be shortened' problems in this file** quick fix available on `Alt+Enter`, `Right`;
To apply fix to all files in project, you can run **Code > Inspect Code...** for the whole project and then use the quick fix (**Replace with a shorter path**) in inspection results to fix all problems

[image]

Comment: Does anybody know if this functionality exists for VSCode?